# Frequency distribution in R

Tags: r, plot, frequency-distribution

I have five columns with numbers. I want to plot the frequency distribution of five columns in one graph with different colors in R. Can some one help me out how i can do this with an example. I am very new to R.

Comment: Please do some research before asking a question: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_(ggplot2)

Comment: post a reproducible example with sample input, expected output and the code that you have tried.

Comment: I have simple length distribution of 5 elements in 5 columns 1st 5 7 8 9 10, 2nd 6 47 484 848 ,3rd 38 383 838 and so on. I just want to have the frequency distribution in bins of say 10 for the whole data set in one histogram plot with different colors.

Answer (score 7):

Using the sample data from @eddi, you can also consider the "lattice" package:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100, 1), c = rnorm(100, 2),
                d = rnorm(100, 3), e = rnorm(100, 4))

library(lattice)

densityplot(~ a + b + c + d + e, data = d)
```

This will yield:

[image]

If you have many columns, you can also create your plot by first creating a `formula`:

```
myFormula <- as.formula(paste("~ ", paste(names(d), collapse = "+"))) 
densityplot(myFormula, data = d)
```

You should also explore the various options available for `densityplot`, such as `plot.points` (which can be set to `FALSE` if you don't want the points at the bottom of the density plots) and `auto.key` to add a legend.

---

Another obvious option is to use "ggplot2", but for this, you need to first convert your data into a "long" format:

```
d2 <- stack(d)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(values, colour=factor(ind), data=d2, geom="density")
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution:

```
d = data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100, 1), c = rnorm(100, 2), d = rnorm(100, 3), e = rnorm(100, 4))

plot(density(d$a), xlim = c(-4, 8))
lines(density(d$b), col = "red")
lines(density(d$c), col = "green")
lines(density(d$d), col = "blue")
lines(density(d$e), col = "yellow")
```

Comment: Add a method to automatically calculate the ranges for `xlim` and `ylim`, and I would be happy to up-vote this answer. :)